# Display TextView after ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview

I want to display `TextView` after `ImageView` but right now Text is coming over Image on my Android screen.

layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="in.sitemakers.sitemakers.AboutFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/about_image"
    android:src="@drawable/sitemakers_laptops"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="420dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/about_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Site Makers is the web development company engage in the.."
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: Preview]

Please see above screenshot and help me update my **`XML`** in such a way so that **`TextView`** will come after **`ImageView`**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace [`FrameLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)  with [`LinearLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) or [`RelativeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) because `FrameLayout` place view one over another

`LinearLayout` : Place child view in linear fashion , one after another either horizontally or vertically.

Note : Linear layout also let you allocate the available width and height among child views dynamically as per assigned `weight` property value.

`RelativeLayout` : 
A Layout where the positions of the children can be described in relation to each other or to the parent

There are many other [`ViewGroups you can use`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) as per the instructions

**Note :** Don't use `px` instead use `dp` as `android:layout_height="420dp"` because `px` represent actual screen pixel which restrict to keep the same size of your views on large screen (views will be quite small) , as mentioned here with [`Density independence`](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence)

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Thanks man, RelativeLayout resolved the issue.

Comment: @AmitGupta then accept this answer if issue is resolved

Comment: @UltimateDevil Yes accepted my dear friend.. Stackoveflow asking me to wait for sometime otherwise accepted earlier :)

Comment: @AmitGupta i am glad that i could help , happy coding and thanks UltimateDevil

Comment: Sir @Pavneet_Singh need a help on this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47001656/7073808)** . Please look at once

Answer (score 1):

You can use linearlayout with orientation="vertical" and Its really easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LinearLayout** or **RelativeLayout**

If You use **LinearLayout** So you can set **orientation="vertical"**

If You use **RelativeLayout** So you can use **android:layout_below="@id/about_image"** in Your TextView.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/about_image"
        android:src="@drawable/sitemakers_laptops"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="420px" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/about_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Site Makers is the web development company engage in the.."/>

    </LinearLayout>
```