# Unable to resolve dependency Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-studio-3.0

It's good to have a Updated **Android Studio 3.0**. But I am facing a problem with **Android Studio 3.0**, I just created a new project in **Android Studio 3.0**. Then I got some error

I solved these by changing **`dependencies`** to latest version and issues solved.

But, when I added a `dependency` of **facebook account-kit sdk** `com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+`

I am getting following errors-:

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+. Open
>   File
> Show Details

**build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ultimate.devil.logintest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**NOTE -:**

- I am following **[Facebook Developers Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/)**
- I have tried by changing `compile` to `implementation`
- I have also tried changing `com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+` to `com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.11.0` and `com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.27` by googling latest version of **Facebook Account-Kit SDK**
- I have also tries StackOverFlow Answers with possible with same problem. But no one help me

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Any luck?

Comment: @BasantMatharu found solution see the answer below.

Comment: Thanks Sir, @Pavneet_Singh.

Comment: Had the same issue and solved it using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949622/android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdexoptions-compilecla/48781062#48781062).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

After some research I have solved this issue.

**Step 1-:**

I disable the **Gradle offline work** in settings.

> File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Uncheck Offline Work

[image]

**Step 2-:**

Then, I just changed **`compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'`** to **`api 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'`**

I don't know exactly why it's work. I see **api** in docs **[Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)**

Now it works :)

**EDIT -**

Now, I am able to use both `api` or `implementation` and everything works fine.

Thanks,

Comment: you are a life safer

Comment: @UltimateDevil can you give me any suggestions in it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027624/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv

Comment: Finding your answer was like: thug life

Answer (score 6):

Add `matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']` in the `buildType` that is failing to compile.

E.g. I was having an error for `releaseStaging`:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '""'
    }
    releaseStaging {
        buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", 'myKey'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        matchingFallbacks = ['release', 'debug']
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", 'myKey'
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am facing similar error day before yesterday. Just solved it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46967876/gradle-stuck-and-taking-long-time-after-updating-android-studio-3-0-stable-updat)

Moreover, as mentioned in the latest gradle release [notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) , you should avoid using dynamic dependencies with version number as:

```
com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+
```

Try to replace it with appropriate version number as 4.0.0 or latest. Hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @prdp89. but as you can see in my question. I had mentioned that i had tried by chnging versions of account-kit sdk

Comment: @UltimateDevil, can we see more descriptive stacktrace of yours?

Comment: unfortunately that's the only stacktrace I am getting in android studio. I have attached screenshot also

Comment: change to full version work for me [implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.34.0']

Comment: meanwhile it's `4.35.0` ...just added an answer with all the build artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

### ***Short story:***

Downgrade to **Gradle 4.2.1**

### ***Long story:***

I was using Gradle version 4.3 based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45685318/2736039) as that question was my error. After doing that change than I started having your problem.

Downgrading to version 4.2.1 your problem went away. Now I have to go back to the previous problem.

I also had this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42574803/incompatible-plugins-for-android-apt-after-upgrading-to-android-studio-2-3) while compiling my project with `Android Studio 3.0` and `gradle plugin 3.0.0`

If I will have other problems I will post here the updates

Comment: Fixed this kind of issue. Have a look .https://stackoverflow.com/a/47101413/1699282

Answer (score 2):

all the Facebook `Account Kit SDK` build artifacts can be found on [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/account-kit-sdk):

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.facebook.android/account-kit-sdk
api 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.35.0'
```

and the according repository to add is:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Gradle not being in `offline` mode, is being assumed.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem by clearing this directory:

```
c:\Users\User name\\.gradle\caches\
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved it by changing `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to **`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`**

Regarding my issue, it was a little bit different from yours. I have the second module with android library and from android developers page under the section *"Convert an app module to a library module"*. My guess is that it is related to managing Manifest files inside of the architecture, so Android will know where is the main Manifest file.

And regarding `api` and `implementation`, the answer can be found [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)

> The api configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are exported by the library API, whereas the implementation configuration should be used to declare dependencies which are internal to the component.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. After trying everything, finally realized that it was the network that didn't allow syncing dependencies. Tried out with hotspot and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I did fix it like this :

```
implementation project(path: 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+', configuration: 'default')
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade these two files solve the problem

project`s build.graddle to 3.1.4
graddle-wrapper properties to 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Saw an old project. It showed "build" successful. So i checked build.gradle file. Comparing those 2 projects i saw a change in dependencies version number. Then i just copied version numbers from the old proj and it worked.  There was one more BuildUsing or so in android{} i removed it from my new proj (it was not in my old proj). i think it is because of an incomplete or corrupt gradle update.