# Elegant number button library is not syncing

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to implement elegant number button in my app, but it's library is not syncing. Here is the gradle file.

```
    //...
    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.1'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.Hitomis:CircleMenu:v1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    compile 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

here is the error:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2.
```

Comment: Try with changing `compile` to `implementation`

Comment: Add you project level gradle in question .

Comment: Did you add `jcenter()` in your project level `build.gradle` section?

Comment: yes, i added but nothing works. please help

Comment: solution?!, i'm have this problem with implements

Answer (score 4):

1. **Replace** `compile` **with** `implementation`
2. **Add**

   `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:replace="android:theme"`

   to your **AndroidManifest.xml** (inside application tag)

   this work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
compile 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
```

With this:

```
implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
```

And also don't forget to add this to your project level build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
// in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think This will  make any difference.

Comment: Which gradle version you are using? can you check once by trying this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47021147/2462531

Answer (score 0):

In your project File->setting check you are working offline or online...if you are working offline you need to be work online to resolve this error..