# unable to Add library to Android

Tags: android

I get this error when I want to add a library to Android:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'



 ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828.
    Show Details
    Affected Modules: app
```

I got this link but didn't get an answer:
[Unable to resolve dependency Android Studio 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001656/unable-to-resolve-dependency-android-studio-3-0)

Comment: update your Build tools,then try File> Invalidate caches/Restart

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a section allprojects at the end of your main build.gradle that defines the repositories for the modules of your project:
build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

hope this will help you.