# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am new to Android. I built a simple login activity (just created it) and it my project is giving this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
```

I tried these solutions and they didnt work:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218535/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001656/unable-to-resolve-dependency-android-studio-3-0
```

My app gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

This is gradle app

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I don't understand how to resolve this issue considering I haven't even added question of my own. Please explain your solution step by step so I'm able to recreate to since this is literally the first project I created.

Comment: It's because there is no support version 29.+. The last version is 28.0.0. The easiest way to update your project is by changing all the 29+ version including compile and buildTools to version 28.0.0, then choose menu `Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX`

Answer (score 0):

1 just figured out how to remove this Gradle error, follow the following steps.

1. Go to "File".
2. Click on Invalidate Cache/ Restart.
3. Again click on Invalidate Cache / Restart(On dialog window).

Let the Gradle build without any interruption

or

2
open the app.
go to gradle scripts.
then build.gradle(module:app)
finally inside dependecies type ( implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
)

Comment: Already tried first one didnt work. I did this second one and it says that this library shouldnt use 27

Answer (score 0):

When you are using

```
   compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
```

Change

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.+'
```

To

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

because google has changed the support libraries for androidX

in app gradle
change

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.android'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: not it says Plugin with id 'com.android.android' not found.

Comment: how can I access them

Comment: in the terminal. And this is only what it is showing

Comment: ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Sorry for replying late, change your dependencies as I have written in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted and reinstalled my android studio. The only thing that worked for me